# JTextField maximum characters length without overlapping characters

Tags: java, swing

What is the maximum length of the string in the text field? We all know that maximum string length is the value of an Integer.MAX_VALUE (2,147,483,647), but that doesn't matter here.

I tried to search on Google and reading Javadoc but nothing appears about that or I'm missing something?

I have the text field for queries. When the length of the string (query) exceeds about 7000 characters, the text becomes unreadable because of the overlapping characters. I have tried also on 2k monitor and there's a threshold at 10k characters, the previous one is 1600x600. I come to the conclusion that is the width size of the text field is a limiting factor in how much it can show without overlapping characters. Is that right or wrong?

I'm trying to find a solution to limit the number of characters in the text field that not cause a character overlapping but not to set a fixed limit of a string length (6000, as I did) but to dynamically define a maximum length of a string in the text field based on some JTextField parameter or text field width or something third.

I hope you understand what is my question here.

Comment: I've always been under the impression that the character limit would be based on multiple factors. Did you try varying the font size in your JTextField? Also, just for fun, why don't you tell us why you're investigating this matter? Typically, people are concerned with limiting the number of characters in a field, not maximizing -- they would just use JTextArea if they had thousands of characters to accept.

Comment: Not understanding your question. 1) I had no problems displaying 30K characters in a JTextField. I even changed the Font to use a size of 24. I use JDK11 on Windows 10. 2) What is the point of trying to display this many characters in a text field? The text field would be unusable. 3) For something like this you should be using a JTextArea. If you expect any more help you need to post a proper  [mre] demonstrating the problem so other can see if they have a problem.

Comment: @MarsAtomic I didn't try a different font size, I should not do that. I'm using this text field for typing a query for elastic and some values are pretty long and have a bunch of them sometimes. And I want to limit a user how much he can append a premade query that not cause overlapping in the text field.

Comment: @camickr I use JDK8. I wanted it first to make a text field from textarea, but I gave up at first on that because there is so much job on making everything right in the panel. I would try If there is no solution for knowing how many characters I can put in text field without overlapping.

Comment: It's probably not a good use of time trying to turn a screwdriver into a hammer when you have an actual hammer nearby. Find a way to lay out your GUI so that you can fit a text area that does the job properly. Have you considered what a user has to go through to visually check a query once it's in the textfield? Navigating through a textfield using arrow keys through a portal that only displays a hundred characters out of a 10k character query sounds miserable.